# Matplotlib plot displays date which is not in the pandas dateframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple data-frame which has a list of 10 days. Out of those 10 days 1 is a holiday. I have assigned a value (1) to each date in the data frame. I am trying to plot the data. The 5th of January is supposed to be a holiday, but it gets printed on the plot even though I have excluded it during the creation of the dictionary using which the data frame was created. My code is as follows.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame, to_datetime

START_DATE = date(2019,1,1)
DATE_LIST = []

for i in range(10):
    DATE = START_DATE + timedelta(i)
    if DATE != date(2019,1,5):
        DATE_LIST.append(DATE)

DATE_DICTIONARY = {}.fromkeys(DATE_LIST, 1)

DATAFRAME = DataFrame({"Value":DATE_DICTIONARY})
DATAFRAME.reindex(to_datetime(DATAFRAME.index)).plot(legend=False)
plt.show()
```

The output when the

```
if DATE != date(2019,1,5):
```

is removed and the 5th of January is also added to the DATE_LIST looks 
something like this

[Figure when the january 5th is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXLv7.png)

I want the exact same format of x axis but, without 5th of januray but upon execution of my code this is what I get.

[Figure when january 5th is excluded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3kRy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not surprising that the number 5 is still present between 4 and 6, independent on if you actually have that number in your data.

If you want to treat dates as categories you can use matplotlib.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame, to_datetime

START_DATE = date(2019,1,1)
DATE_LIST = []

for i in range(10):
    DATE = START_DATE + timedelta(i)
    if DATE != date(2019,1,5):
        DATE_LIST.append(DATE)

DATE_DICTIONARY = {}.fromkeys(DATE_LIST, 1)

df = DataFrame({"Value":DATE_DICTIONARY})
df = df.reindex(to_datetime(df.index))

plt.plot(df.index.astype(str), df.values)
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But, I need the format that is there in the first picture I have posted.

Comment: That format can only be obtained with pandas formatters.

Comment: If the if statement is replaced with if DATE.weekday() != 5 and if DATE.weekday() != 6. Then it skips the Saturdays and sundays and maintains the format I posted first. If that is possible, why can't we skip some dates in between and still treat te xaxis as dates ?

Comment: Pandas seems to use [some heuristics](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/179822a0a5b3e84c841bcb76e72a269d13cd3aad/pandas/plotting/_timeseries.py#L256) as to which locator/formatter to use. One would need to dive deep into this to still use the `TimeSeries_DateLocator` from pandas but with custom non-buisiness-days.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much. Now I understand.